# How do I compute the moving average age of a product from the first day it is purchased?

Tags: r, tableau-api, moving-average, calculation

I have a series of random data points with order date, expiry date and product category.

I am trying to compute 2 age variables, wherein 1 would compute the rolling age using just the order date (hence no expiry date) between order dates.

In other words, I don't need age determined based on current date but ones' relative to each data point in the data. As such, the average would keep increasing as more products are purchased and first ones get old. The second age variable would essentially cap each order by expiry date, which would mean the rolling average would not necessarily be increasing.

I am trying to do this using R or Tableau.

Comment: What's your issue? What have you tried and what went wrong? Also please add language tag.

Comment: @barbsan I have been using a rolling window calculation in both R and Tableau but I do realise that by using the TODAY() date, it gives me a static computation based on date today. I would rather see the data compute the rolling average as and when new orders are added using their dates as references.